# Stylecop - Is class x in my inheritance hierarchy?

Tags: c#, inheritance, hierarchy, stylecop

Is there a way to check if my element with elementtype class has a certain other class in his inheritance hierarchy?

My usecase is: I have to check if my Exceptions are prefixed with "Exception". To do so, i have to somehow determine if a certain class is an exception. The only way i can be sure is if it is inherited by the Exception class itself.

Checking the baseclass type for being an exception is easy enough, but imagine the following scenario:

```
class GenericMathException : Exception{}
class SpecificMathException : GenericMathException{}
```

The only information i can get about the `SpecificMathException` is that it's baseclass type is `GenericMathException`, but i can't go any further up in it's inheritance hierarchy.

The usual approach of reflection can't be used too, afaik.

So, anyone ever had to deal with this problem and found a solution? Or has any alternative approach to identify Exceptions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Huh? What does this have to do with StyleCop?

Comment: This is only really a problem when walking the code via Stylecop, not a general question. It's the "external view" that makes this problematic.

Comment: I assume he wants to create a StyleCop rule. But I think this would work better as an FxCop rule. As I see it StyleCop is for enforcing rules are the source file level and FxCop at the compiled assembly level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By its nature, StyleCop indeed works only with the contents of the file and can not use information from the assembly itself.

But, if you ask about "alternative approach to identify Exceptions", there is a rule in [StyleCop+](http://stylecopplus.codeplex.com/) which performs a checking very close to yours. You specify a list of base classes (`Attribute`, `Exception`, `EventArgs` and `Stream` by default), and it ensures that all classes inherited from them have the name that ends with `...Attribute`, `...Exception` and so on.

The checking works in the following way. If the name of the base class ends with a string from the list, it ensures that the name of the inherited class should also end with the same string. E.g., if it meets `Class2 : InvalidOperationException` or `Class2 : SomeUnknownException`, it will raise a violation in both cases.

Assuming that you follow this rule, all your inherited classes will always be named well, even if they are multi-inherited. The only thing that can not be checked in this way, is the situation where you deal with some classes not from "yours" assembly, that already have broken this rule. E.g., if some assembly has `Class2 : Exception`, and you reference this assembly as a binary (and do not have a chance to check it with StyleCop) then you will not be able to check if your `Class3` inherited from `Class2` should be prefixed with `...Exception`.

But practice shows that the last issue is rather rare, so the method described above works really well for StyleCop.

Comment: Thanks alot, implemented it that way. Only quirk that remains is, if you happen to have Class1 : Exception and Class2 : Class1, you will only see the warning belonging to Class1, and once you fixed that, the warning belonging to Class2 in the second run. But anyway, that scenario is rare enough to be acceptable.